# Issue when writing to elasticsearch using es-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

Am getting this exception when I'm trying to write to Elasticsearch using mapreduce program with es-hadoop. Am trying to write to ***index=employee and type=basic*** which already exists in my Elasticsearch cluster.

My stack trace :-

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: No resource
>   ['es.resource'] (index/query/location) specified  at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:30)  at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat.init(EsOutputFormat.java:257)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(EsOutputFormat.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)  at
>   com.mstack.mapreduce.DIGDriver.main(DIGDriver.java:22)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

**Driver class :-**

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "es-hadoop");
job.setJarByClass(DIGDriver.class);
conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost:9200");
conf.set("es.port", "9200");
conf.set("es.resource", "employee/basic");
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
job.setOutputFormatClass(EsOutputFormat.class);
job.setMapperClass(DIGMapper.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(MapWritable.class);
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.map.speculative", false);
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.reduce.speculative", false);
boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (status) {
System.exit(0);
} else {
System.out.println("Job Failed : Some error!");
System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved myself by changing the configs :-

```
conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost");
conf.set("es.port", "9200");
```